# Type FBSessionState does not conform to protocol AnyObject

Tags: facebook, swift, xcode6

Hi guys trying to convert objective c facebook custom login to swift so I am creating a NSDictionary to store the status and session , but I am not able to add FBSessionState object in NSDictionary 
 My Code is below

```
   FBSession.openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions(permission, allowLoginUI: allowLogin, completionHandler: { (session , status, error) -> Void in
           var dict : NSDictionary =  NSDictionary ()
           dict.setValue(status, forKey: "status")



})
```

I get Type FBSessionState does not conform to protocol AnyObject error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure but maybe NSDictionary does not accept enum value. I suggest you to use 'Dictionary' instead of `NSDictionary`